# Salesforce retrieve object data

Tags: php, salesforce, soql

So far, this query works fine `SELECT * FROM Contact`, which retrieves all contacts from the Contact object, but now I'm trying to fetch data from Education__c, so I tried `SELECT * FROM Education__c`. This is what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Education__c";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
foreach($response->records as $record){
        echo ($record->fields->School_Name__c);
```

But this doesn't work. So I guess I'm doing something wrong with the response->records but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL doesn't like wildcards [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm). Try specifying the fields you want to retrieve. Also, does it give you any errors?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. But Now I'm trying http://pastebin.com/QzNEJLZ0 that, and still no good.

Comment: They're two different types of tables. Contact is a default system table, Education__c is a user-created table. I've found that SOQL is a very picky language.

Comment: For user created table/objects, accessing it should be the same as Contact right?

Comment: You'd think. I'm actually surprised that it works for the Contact table. As the link I pointed out, it doesn't support wildcards for field lists. I've googled and found a few sites that support the SOQL KB.

Comment: t.t Ugh, I hate soql. Thanks for helping!